# how to develop online java code compiler UI using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking for solution to develop UI for compiling java code ,so that i can compile and replace the class files deployed to server.

usage case: i need a UI to run my java code snippet to replace the class files from the local to server.

Comment: This is a very dangerous endeavour. And it seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Which problem do you want to *actually* solve?

Comment: @lexicore : basically i need to patch class files to server code so that  i can avoid deployment process, can you suggest what will be best way to do it?

Comment: Firstly, patch class files to server code is not really a good idea, it's dangerous and uncontrollable. But if you have quiet good reason to do so, you can just upload complied `.class` files instead of compiling online.

Comment: @sharan Patching server code instead of a clean deployment is a road to hell. Especially the way you want to do it with uploading code via UI. Do not do it.